# Response from WCF service throwing CommunicationException

Tags: c#, wcf

First, please allow me to post my problematic code!!!...

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents the implementation of the Remote Launch Service.
/// </summary>
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
[KnownType(typeof(RemoteProcessHandle))]
[KnownType(typeof(RemoteLaunchServiceResult<RemoteProcessHandle>))]
[KnownType(typeof(RemoteLaunchServiceResult<bool>))]
public sealed class RemoteLaunchService : IRemoteLaunchService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the event in which a process is started by the Remote Launch Service.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">the object that raised the event.</param>
    /// <param name="startInfo">the <see cref="RemoteProcessStartInfo"/> object containing information about the process that was started.</param>
    /// <param name="handle">the <see cref="RemoteProcessHandle"/> for the resulting process.</param>
    public delegate void ProcessStartedEventHandler(
        object sender, RemoteProcessStartInfo startInfo, RemoteProcessHandle handle);

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the event in which an attempt to close the main window of a process is made by the Remote Launch Service.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">the object that raised the event.</param>
    /// <param name="handle">the <see cref="RemoteProcessHandle"/> corresponding to the process.</param>
    /// <param name="successful">true if the operation was successful, otherwise false.</param>
    public delegate void ProcessMainWindowClosedEventHandler(
        object sender, RemoteProcessHandle handle, bool successful);

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the event in which a process is killed by the Remote Launch Service.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">the object that raised the event.</param>
    /// <param name="handle">the <see cref="RemoteProcessHandle"/> corresponding to the process.</param>
    public delegate void ProcessKilledEventHandler(
        object sender, RemoteProcessHandle handle);

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the event in which an exception is thrown by the Remote Launch Service.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">the object that raised the event.</param>
    /// <param name="exception">the exception that was thrown.</param>
    public delegate void ExceptionThrownEventHandler(
        object sender, Exception exception);

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the event in which a process is started by the Remote Launch Service.
    /// </summary>
    public event ProcessStartedEventHandler ProcessStarted;

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the event in which an attempt to close the main window of a process is made by the Remote Launch Service.
    /// </summary>
    public event ProcessMainWindowClosedEventHandler ProcessMainWindowClosed;

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the event in which a process is killed by the Remote Launch Service.
    /// </summary>
    public event ProcessKilledEventHandler ProcessKilled;

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the event in which an exception is thrown by the Remote Launch Service.
    /// </summary>
    public event ExceptionThrownEventHandler ExceptionThrown;

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts a remote process via the Remote Launch Service, using information within the specified <see cref="RemoteProcessStartInfo"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="startInfo">the <see cref="RemoteProcessStartInfo"/> object containing information about the process to start.</param>
    /// <returns>a <see cref="RemoteLaunchServiceResult{RemoteProcessHandle}"/> containing a <see cref="RemoteProcessHandle"/> for the process.</returns>
    public RemoteLaunchServiceResult<RemoteProcessHandle> Start(
        RemoteProcessStartInfo startInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            // Start the process and retrieve the handle.
            RemoteProcessHandle handle = new RemoteProcessHandle(Process.Start(startInfo.LocalProcessStartInfo));

            // If there are any handlers registered to the appropriate event, raise it.
            if (ProcessStarted != null) ProcessStarted(this, startInfo, handle);

            // Return the result containing the handle.
            return new RemoteLaunchServiceResult<RemoteProcessHandle>(handle, null);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // If an exception is thrown, raise the appropriate event (if any handlers are registered to it), and return the result containing the exception.
            if (ExceptionThrown != null) ExceptionThrown(this, exception);
            return new RemoteLaunchServiceResult<RemoteProcessHandle>(null, exception.Message);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to close the main window of the process corresponding to the specified <see cref="RemoteProcessHandle"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="handle">the <see cref="RemoteProcessHandle"/> corresponding to the process.</param>
    /// <returns>a <see cref="RemoteLaunchServiceResult{bool}"/> containing whether the operation was successful or not.</returns>
    public RemoteLaunchServiceResult<bool> CloseMainWindow(
        RemoteProcessHandle handle)
    {
        try
        {
            // Attempt to close the main window of the process and retrieve whether this was successful.
            bool successful = handle.LocalProcess.CloseMainWindow();

            // If there are any handlers registered to the appropriate event, raise it.
            if (ProcessMainWindowClosed != null) ProcessMainWindowClosed(this, handle, successful);

            // Return the result containing whether the operation was successful or not.
            return new RemoteLaunchServiceResult<bool>(successful, null);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // If an exception is thrown, raise the event (if any handlers are registered to it), and return the result containing the exception.
            if (ExceptionThrown != null) ExceptionThrown(this, exception);
            return new RemoteLaunchServiceResult<bool>(false, exception.Message);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Kills the process corresponding to the specified <see cref="RemoteProcessHandle"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="handle">the <see cref="RemoteProcessHandle"/> corresponding to the process.</param>
    /// <returns>a <see cref="RemoteLaunchServiceResult{bool}"/> containing whether an exception was thrown or not.</returns>
    public RemoteLaunchServiceResult<bool> Kill(
        RemoteProcessHandle handle)
    {
        try
        {
            handle.LocalProcess.Kill();

            // If there are any handlers registered to the appropriate event, raise it.
            if (ProcessKilled != null) ProcessKilled(this, handle);

            // Return the result indicating that no exception was thrown.
            return new RemoteLaunchServiceResult<bool>(true, null);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // If an exception is thrown, raise the event (if any handlers are registered to it), and return the result containing the exception.
            if (ExceptionThrown != null) ExceptionThrown(this, exception);
            return new RemoteLaunchServiceResult<bool>(false, exception.Message);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The default port number used by the Remote Launch Service.
    /// </summary>
    public const int DefaultPort = 2185;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the address of the Remote Launch Service running on the specified machine, using the specified port number.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="machineName">the name of the machine.</param>
    /// <param name="port">the port number.</param>
    /// <returns>a <see cref="string"/> containing the address.</returns>
    public static string GetAddress(
        string machineName, int port)
    {
        // The machine name and port number must be valid.
        if (machineName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(machineName));
        if ((port < IPEndPoint.MinPort) || (port > IPEndPoint.MaxPort)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(port));

        // Derive and return the address.
        return string.Format(@"net.tcp://{0}:{1}/RemoteLaunchService", machineName, port);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the address of the Remote Launch Service running on this machine, using the specified port number.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="port">the port number.</param>
    /// <returns>a <see cref="string"/> containing the address.</returns>
    public static string GetAddress(
        int port)
    {
        return GetAddress(Dns.GetHostName(), port);
    }
}
```

I'm accessing the service via the `ChannelFactory` class, and all goes well until I hit the return statement in my `Start()` method...

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Starts a remote process via the Remote Launch Service, using information within the specified <see cref="RemoteProcessStartInfo"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="startInfo">the <see cref="RemoteProcessStartInfo"/> object containing information about the process to start.</param>
    /// <returns>a <see cref="RemoteLaunchServiceResult{RemoteProcessHandle}"/> containing a <see cref="RemoteProcessHandle"/> for the process.</returns>
    public RemoteLaunchServiceResult<RemoteProcessHandle> Start(
        RemoteProcessStartInfo startInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            // Start the process and retrieve the handle.
            RemoteProcessHandle handle = new RemoteProcessHandle(Process.Start(startInfo.LocalProcessStartInfo));

            // If there are any handlers registered to the appropriate event, raise it.
            if (ProcessStarted != null) ProcessStarted(this, startInfo, handle);

            // Return the result containing the handle.
            return new RemoteLaunchServiceResult<RemoteProcessHandle>(handle, null);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // If an exception is thrown, raise the appropriate event (if any handlers are registered to it), and return the result containing the exception.
            if (ExceptionThrown != null) ExceptionThrown(this, exception);
            return new RemoteLaunchServiceResult<RemoteProcessHandle>(null, exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

The code correctly executes the process as required without entering the catch block, but a `CommunicationException` is thrown as soon as I return the `RemoteLaunchServiceResult`. Interestingly, if I change...

```
            return new RemoteLaunchServiceResult<RemoteProcessHandle>(handle, null);
```

...to...

```
            return new RemoteLaunchServiceResult<RemoteProcessHandle>(null, null);
```

...no exception is thrown, making me think it may be a problem with the `RemoteProcessHandle` class. Here is a listing of this class...

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents the information required to access a remote process after it has been started by the Remote Launch Service.
/// </summary>
[Serializable]
public sealed class RemoteProcessHandle : ISerializable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RemoteProcessHandle"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="process">the <see cref="Process"/> object to derive the handle from.</param>
    public RemoteProcessHandle(
        Process process)
    {
        if (process == null) return;

        try { this.processID = process.Id; } catch { }
        try { this.machineName = process.MachineName; } catch { }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RemoteProcessHandle"/> class from data contained within a <see cref="SerializationInfo"/> object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="info">the <see cref="SerializationInfo"/> containing the information required to deserialize this <see cref="RemoteProcessHandle"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="context">the <see cref="StreamingContext"/> containing the source of the serialized stream associated with this <see cref="RemoteProcessHandle"/>.</param>
    public RemoteProcessHandle(
        SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : this(null)
    {
        try { this.processID = (int?)info.GetValue(nameof(this.processID), typeof(int?)); } catch { }
        try { this.machineName = (string)info.GetValue(nameof(this.machineName), typeof(string)); } catch { }
    }

    // Instance variables.
    private int? processID = null;
    private string machineName = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the ID of the process that this <see cref="RemoteProcessHandle"/> represents.
    /// </summary>
    public int? ProcessID
    {
        get { return this.processID; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the name of the machine running the process that this <see cref="RemoteProcessHandle"/> represents.
    /// </summary>
    public string MachineName
    {
        get { return this.machineName; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the local <see cref="Process"/> corresponding to this <see cref="RemoteProcessHandle"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public Process LocalProcess
    {
        get
        {
            // The machine name within this information has got to match this machine, and the process ID mustn't be null.
            if (!Dns.GetHostName().Equals(this.MachineName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) throw new InvalidOperationException();
            if (this.ProcessID == null) throw new InvalidOperationException();

            // Get and return the process.
            return Process.GetProcessById(this.ProcessID.Value);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the address of the Remote Launch Service, using the specified port number, running the process that this <see cref="RemoteProcessHandle"/> represents.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="port">the port number.</param>
    /// <returns>a <see cref="string"/> containing the address.</returns>
    public string GetRemoteLaunchServiceAddress(
        int port)
    {
        return RemoteLaunchService.GetAddress(this.MachineName, port);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Populates a <see cref="SerializationInfo"/> object with data required to serialize this <see cref="RemoteProcessHandle"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="info">the <see cref="SerializationInfo"/> to contain the information required to serialize this <see cref="RemoteProcessHandle"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="context">the <see cref="StreamingContext"/> containing the destination of the serialized stream associated with this <see cref="RemoteProcessHandle"/>.</param>
    public void GetObjectData(
        SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue(nameof(this.processID), this.processID, typeof(int?));
        info.AddValue(nameof(this.machineName), this.machineName, typeof(string));
    }
}
```

Please could anybody offer any suggestions as to what could be causing this exception to be thrown?

Comment: Have you tried [WCF tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see if you can get more detail for the exception?

Comment: You may also wish to declare RemoteProcessHandle as a [DataContract] with [DataMember] properties: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Add Process as known type

Comment: @PrasanthVJ Would I need to add Process as a known type, as it isn't involved in the serialization (being as my class inherits ISerializable, so the DataContractSerializer should use the custom serialization code that only serializes the .processID and .machineName fields).

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to fix this error!...

```
[Serializable]
[KnownType(typeof(RemoteProcessHandle))]
public sealed class RemoteLaunchServiceResult<T>
{
    // I solved the problem by adding the "KnownType" attribute. I thought
    // it would have worked having it in the "RemoteLaunchService" class,
    // but I was wrong!
}
```

Thanks for your input guys!!!